# Handled Exception in primitive webservice returns 500 error instead of new SOAP exception that is thrown

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have an application written in C# primitive web service technology.

Problem: Schema validation exception wrapped by the validation class handled via event handler to throw a new SOAP exception will show up the result with the message thrown via SOAP exception. Expected.

However if we need more validation for an input message which cannot be achieved via xml validation, done from the code behind, throw new exception with desired message and using the same event handler function to return message(SOAP exception with new message) is resulting in the 500 error.

What I suspect is the event handler for validation is a seperate thread, while the second case is a new exception thrown in the main thread resulting in server side faulting?